# error in handling set of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

I'm new to Standard template library and i wanted to store overlapping subsequences. Since a set ignores duplicates. I have a set of vectors:

```
set<vector<int> > subsequences;
```

but when i try to insert into this set:

```
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
subsequences.insert(arr);
```

I get an error:

```
coinChange.cpp:20:18: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    subsequences.insert(arr);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/set:596:25: note:
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<long long, allocator<long
      long>>' to 'const vector<int, allocator<int>>' for 1st argument
    pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& __v)
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/set:613:14: note:
      candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        void insert(_InputIterator __f, _InputIterator __l)
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/set:604:14: note:
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    iterator insert(const_iterator __p, const value_type& __v)
         ^
```

Since i'm new to STL, i am not able to understand what i'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: What is `arr` declared as?  There are no issues here: http://ideone.com/xtFKx9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error, you more than likely declared a `std::vector<long, long>` and assumed this is compatible with a `std::vector<int>`.  This is not the case.

If `T` and `U` are different types, then a `std::vector<T>` and a `std::vector<U>` are also different types.  In your case `T` is an `int`, and `U` is a `long long`.

The following code compiles correctly:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::set<vector<int> > subsequences;    
    std::vector<int> arr;
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    subsequences.insert(arr);
}
```

while the following code produces the errors you're seeing:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::set<vector<int> > subsequences;    
    std::vector<long long> arr;
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    subsequences.insert(arr);
}
```

So the obvious fix is to make sure you're using the same types.  One way to ensure this is to use a `typedef`, and make sure this is used in your code base to denote the vector type to use:

```
//...
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;  // change this to long long if needed
//...
std::set<IntVector> subsequences;
IntVector arr;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says what's wrong:

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<long long, allocator<long long>>' to 'const vector<int, allocator<int>>' for 1st argument
```

You're trying to pass a `vector<long long>` into `set<vector<int>>::insert`. `vector<long long>` is a different type than `vector<int>`, and that's why it doesn't work. To fix it, use the same type of vector throughout.

Answer (score 0):

The error says "no known conversion from `vector<**long long**, allocator<long
      long>>` to `const vector<**int**, allocator<int>>`

Looks like you are trying to insert a vector of long long in a set that is supposed to contain a vector of ints.